# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class BUT ist initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, model, device, null

Hey i´ve got another problem ;)

When i try to create a new Book in my app it always says

`undefined method "model_name" for NilClass:Class`

I found out that it must be an uninitialized param in the Form_for function... Here my code:

`NoMethodError in Books#new`

`Showing /app/views/books/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:`

```
   undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
   Extracted source (around line #1):

   1: <%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
   2:   <% if @book.errors.any? %>
   3:     <div id="error_explanation">
   4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>
```

Controller:

```
   #GET /books/new
   #GET /books/new.json
   def new
     @users = User.find(:all)
     @book = Book.new
     1.times{ @book.chapters.build }
     @book.users = [current_user]
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html #new.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @book }
     end
    end
```

I don´t know why it should be uninitialized, it worked properly before I changed some relations between Books and Users but I there shoudn´t be the failure or?

EDIT:

app/views/books/new.html.erb :

```
    <h1>New book</h1>

    <%= render 'form' %>

    <%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
```

And the Model :

```
   class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
            attr_accessible :abstract, :status, :titel, :user_tokens, user_ids,        :chapters_attributes

     has_and_belongs_to_many :users
     attr_reader :user_tokens

     has_many :chapters, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true, :order => 'slot'

     validates :title, :presence => true

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :chapters, :allow_destroy => true

     after_initialize :init
     def init
       self.status = false if self.status?
     end

     def user_tokens=(ids)
       self.user_ids = ids.split(",")
     end

   end
   end
```

Comment: What does app/views/books/new.html.erb look like?

Comment: Can you also show use what your Book model looks like?

Comment: I wonder too whether this is a model. You can always use the debugger and check what it looks like before it renders

Comment: See new.html.erb and Book Model in my updated post

Comment: Sometimes i get this Error: undefined local variable or method `user_ids' for #<Class:0x46fb6a8>

Answer (score 0):

Your partial will not know the instance variables you set up in the controller. You will have to pass them as locals when you render the partial

```
render :partial => "form", :locals => {:book => @book}
```

And in your partial, use `book` instead of `@book`

```
<%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
   <% if book.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>
```

Comment: I didn´t get your solution to work, where do i have to paste the line for the partial rendering exactly?

Comment: In your books/new.html.erb. line 2

Comment: then i got this error : undefined local variable or method `book' for #<#<Class:0x462cbd0>:0x28c1e68>

Comment: Did you add `render :partial => "form", :locals => {:book => @book}` or `render "form", :locals => {:book => @book}` ?

Comment: I tryed http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html point 3.4.4 Passing Local Variables but then i got first error....

Comment: Ok I´ve got the same situation with chapters but there are no problems with the view and rendering partials (thare also @chapters in the form which got rendered from new without passing anything )

Comment: I think it must be something with my m:n relationship between Books an Chapters because that´s the last thing i worked on ???

Comment: Do you mind posting the full stacktrace of the error you are getting when you add the render partial with locals?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33295/discussion-between-enno-and-vimsha)

Comment: No sure I will give you what ever you need, but stacktrace? I´ve got a Application ,Framwork or Fulltrace but no stacktrace? Sorry I´m very new to rails... if it would help I can give you the entire App (Sourcecode)

Comment: Ok I got a solution, I removed the attr_accessible  :user_ids in the books model and the Book.new view works... but why??